# Silverlight combo popup not displayed correctly when window resizes

Tags: silverlight, combobox, popup

If I create a `ComboBox` from scratch, when the window is resized, the content is correctly displayed above/below, etc.

Why this doesn't happen when you create your own Combo-derived class? What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean "when the window is resized, the content is correctly displayed above/below"?

Comment: when the window is resized, the comboboxitems are displayed in the remaining space(up/down/left/right) near the combobox

Comment: yes. but in basic combobox have same problem too.

Comment: I can reproduce that bug on original combobox

Answer (score 0):

Controls aren't magical. They need to be told that things happen (call a method on them) or look for them to happen (register for an event).

Find your [Application.RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.rootvisual%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and register for a [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. Then resize your control. If it is in browser you may need to create a javascript bridge (hopefully not) that tells your SL object when the browser resizes.

Comment: but since my control is derived from a standard combobox, what could go wrong?